# Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память при вызове openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()?

Tags: c#

Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена. Происходит при вызове `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()`. Собственно из-за чего может такое происходить?

Answer (score 1):

Вирус, повреждение жесткого диска, "закрученные" свойства у OpenFileDialog1

Comment: Но дело в том, что если создать новую форму и там запустить OpenFileDialog1, то все отлично, да и в других формах проекта тоже. Проблема именно в одной форме из проекта. На вирусы я проверял, не нашел, да и свойства я не менял у OpenFileDialog1.

Comment: Тогда нужен код самой этой формы, очень даже любопытно, что в ней может повлиять на такое поведение. Может, во время вашей разработки в редакторе форм вы сделали что-то не так, так что есть еще полускрытый файл *.designer.cs. В нем может нарушится авторазметка этих файлов. Просмотрите, пожалуйста, код, особенно что касается вашего компонента.